# Proton flux model or data at energy range up to 100 keV

Tags: particle-physics, specific-reference, sun, protons, particle-detectors

I am looking for a model or at best the database of proton fluxes (solar p+) at a energy range of some eV up to 100 keV. I have already found the SOHO database:

http://umtof.umd.edu/pm/

But the most energetic p+ was something around 5 keV. Still, I need fluxes from 5 keV up to 100 keV.

Is there any database, and maybe a reference to a mathematical model?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at data from the [ACE](http://www.srl.caltech.edu/ACE/) and [Wind](http://wind.nasa.gov) spacecraft at NASA's [SPDF CDAWeb](http://cdaweb.gsfc.nasa.gov).  Both of these spacecraft have solid state telescopes that go up to tens to thousands of keV for protons.  The data is freely available to anyone.